# Is canvas faster than a normal image?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, performance, photo

So If I have for example an image like this:

[image]

Will it load faster if its written in JS, in canvas? Or is it faster to have it in PNG or JPG or GIF?

Comment: Seems to me that this is a tradeoff of bandwidth vs. execution time, and one answer isn't going to hold true for all images.

Comment: haha. I'm happy then, @Ish Kumar :D

Comment: Just to be clear, by "written in JS" I assume you mean doing the math to actually render it, not just loading an image via JS and drawing it to a canvas.  Is that right?

Comment: No one's mentioned it yet, so I will - the JavaScript solution will fail if the end user has JavaScript disabled :)

Comment: @Russ Cam this is true, but today almost everyone has JS enabled :)

Comment: @Russ Cam IE is a problem, too.

Comment: @Alex JL - very true for IE < 9 (excanvas might be able to help in older versions somewhat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your network latency, and for images of nontrivial size, on the bandwidth available both on your server's end and on the user's end. High latency and low bandwidth would increase the odds that a canvas-based solution would be faster.

Canvas-based image drawing speed also varies drastically betweeen browsers. Here are some fairly outdated results:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/canvas-benchmark

Since then Chrome has advanced 4 versions, the Firefox team has put a lot of work into performance in Firefox 4, and IE9 has arrived with hardware acceleration. But it can give you an idea of the variability at least.